# Multiply different sized dataframes after comparing values of first columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to using DataFrames, so please bear with me. So I have two different sized dataframes like the following:

```
df1 =
        name  var1  var2  var3
    0   0001  1.08  0.89  1.98  
    1   0002  2.11  0.19  1.64
    2   0003  1.45  1.22  1.21
    3   0004  1.32  1.34  2.01  

df2 =
        name  var1  var2  var3
    0   0002   10    25    12  
    1   0001   21    31    12
    2   0002   25    14    24  
    3   0004   13    21    11
    4   0003   24    55    41
    5   0004   26    14    61
    6   0001   16    19    36
    7   0003   20    18    44
```

What I am trying to do is to compare the first column to match the names and multiply the columns of var1, var2 and var3 of the corresponding rows with each other, so it results in a dataframe of the same length as df2:

```
df3 = 
        name     var1   var2     var3
    0   0002   2.11*10 0.19*25  1.64*12  
    1   0001   1.08*21 0.89*31  1.98*12
    2   0002      .       .       .
    3   0004      .       .       .
    4   0003      .       .       .
    5   0004      .       .       .
    6   0001      .       .       .
    7   0003      .       .       .
```

I've tried to compare the first column like this:

```
variables = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']
for var in variables:
   if (df1['name'] == df2['name']:
      print(df1[var] * df2[var])
```

But that gives me a

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Is there any way to get the result I would like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use "name" as index to align the dataframes, then a simple multiplication will work.

The tricky part is to keep track of the original index. For that you can set it as column and use a dummy index made of 1 for df1, so that the multiplication won't affect it:

```
(df2.reset_index()
    .set_index('name')
    .mul(df1.set_index('name').assign(index=1))
    .reset_index()
    .set_index('index')
    .sort_index()
)
```

output:

```
       name   var1   var2    var3
index                            
0         2  21.10   4.75   19.68
1         1  22.68  27.59   23.76
2         2  52.75   2.66   39.36
3         4  17.16  28.14   22.11
4         3  34.80  67.10   49.61
5         4  34.32  18.76  122.61
6         1  17.28  16.91   71.28
7         3  29.00  21.96   53.24
```